# how $e=\text{number of elements of $G'/G$}=2$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Consider $\Bbb Q_3$ and its quadratic extension $\Bbb Q_3(\sqrt{3})$. I want to find the ramification index $e$.

We have the valuation groups as follows:

For $\Bbb Q_3$, the valuation group $G=\{|a|_3: a \in \Bbb Q_3, \ a \neq 0 \}$ is generated by $3$,

For $\Bbb Q_3(\sqrt{3})$, the valuation group $G'=\{|b|: b \in \Bbb Q_3, \ b \neq 0 \}$ is generated by $\sqrt 3$.

Thus,
$e=\text{number of elements of $G'/G$}= ?$

As $\Bbb Q_3(\sqrt 3)$ is ramified, so $e=2$.

But how $e=\text{number of elements of $G'/G$}=2$ ?

Can you explain it please?

Comment: ${\sqrt 3}^ℤ / 3^ℤ = {\sqrt 3}^ℤ / ({\sqrt 3}^2)^ℤ \cong ℤ/2ℤ$ by the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @k.stm, Is it $\sqrt {3}^{\Bbb Z}/\sqrt {3}^{2^\Bbb Z}$ or is it $\sqrt {3}^{\Bbb Z}/\sqrt {3}^{2 \Bbb Z}$ ? Also what is the homomorphism here? Is it $f: \sqrt 3^{\Bbb Z} \to \Bbb Z/2 \Bbb Z$ defined by $f(\sqrt 3^x)=x \ \mod \ 2$ ?

Comment: It’s $({\sqrt 3}^2)^ℤ = {\sqrt 3}^{2ℤ}$ and the map is $ℤ → {\sqrt 3}^ℤ,~k ↦ {\sqrt 3}^k$ postcomposed with the projection, so
$$ℤ → {\sqrt 3}^ℤ → {\sqrt 3}^ℤ / 3^ℤ,~1 ↦ [\sqrt 3]_{3^ℤ}.$$
It’s surjective and its kernel is the preimage of $3^ℤ$ under the first map, which is $2ℤ$, because for $k ∈ ℤ$
$${\sqrt 3}^k ∈ 3^ℤ \iff 2 \mid k \iff k ∈ 2ℤ.$$